# Axial and vectorial couplings of fermion

Tags: standard-model, fermions, dirac-equation, beyond-the-standard-model, bosons

From some of the review papers that i read, there is a phrase, Dirac fermions have just vectorial couplings to the $Z'_{B-L}$ boson.

Good day, what does axial coupling and vectorial coupling means? and what is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A  vector coupling to a gauge boson $V_\mu$ is
$$
\propto  V_\mu \bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \psi ~.
$$
This is how fermions couple to the photon in QED, for instance.

An axial coupling, by contrast,  presents as
$$
\propto  V_\mu \bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \gamma^5\psi ~.
$$

Review, e.g., the axial couplings of the Z boson in (10.2) [here](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2020/reviews/rpp2020-rev-standard-model.pdf).

Comment: Thank you sir for the reference.